# Custom UIActivity : image icon inverted color

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller, custom-activity

For Custom UIActivity, activity image icon color is inverted,which is supposed to be in black and white.
Please suggest me the answer.

My code to add image:

```
- (UIImage *)activityImage {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"openWith.png"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the **expected behavior**. Probably **Apple** wanted to differentiate between default share apps and custom activities. That's why may be they have done so.